# itextpdf generating broken link

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I have two problems with itext 7. One of them is that if you introduce a link that is longer than one line, the first line is presented as its own link, only the second line is refering to the whole thing. The second problem is about adding a border around a link. That border is only present for the second half of the link (which is probably related to the first problem). Is there a proper way to remove these borders, and how should I insert link, to be properly handled.

This is what I've tried:

```
final Link link = new Link(row, PdfAction.createURI(row));
final Paragraph p = new Paragraph(link).setFont(f1).setFontColor(Color.BLUE)
                            .setUnderline();
document.add(p);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is a known iText7 bug. It's being investigated.
The second problem is easily fixed.

```
PdfAnnotation la1 = new PdfLinkAnnotation(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0))
    .setHighlightMode(PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT)
    .setAction(js)
    .setBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_UNDERLINE); // this is what you need
```

Comment: By the way, is there a way to track this bug? It would be worth to check every once in a while, if we still have to use one-line placeholders.

Comment: We do make the effort of updating SO posts/comments if the bug has been solved. But we're only human. Sometimes we forget.
You can of course check the release notes of our releases. That should tell you whether a bug is fixed.